# How to add page number option in footer with DynamicJasper API?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am creating report with help of code:

```
FastReportBuilder fr = new FastReportBuilder();
```

I want to add page number in footer of each page like.

```
page 1/3
page 2/3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [documented in the HOW-TO](http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-create-autotext-ie-page-xy-out-of-the-box/) something like this:

```
FastReportBuilder fr = new FastReportBuilder();
fr.addAutoText(
    AutoText.AUTOTEXT_PAGE_X_SLASH_Y,
    AutoText.POSITION_FOOTER,
    AutoText.ALIGNMENT_LEFT
)
```